# How to render two or more images on a video frame in the same draw call using Metal?

Tags: metal

I'm a newbie to graphics programming and I have an existing code base which basically takes frame from video and passes it to a metal shader where effects (like colour changes) happen.

What is currently happening?

I can use the existing method to send an image as a texture and it gets blended with the original frame and a new frame is created.

What do I want to achieve?

I want to place multiple images on the original image in the same drawing call. What would be the best way to achieve this? Should I change the existing render pipeline or can the shader handle it?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the effect you want to achieve? There are lots of ways to add images to a video effect, and we might use different techniques  depending on the goal.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed us some of your current code. But in general, you can add textures to your shader and then set them up in code by using [`-[MTLRenderCommandEncoder setFragmentTexture:atIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515390-setfragmenttexture?language=objc). It may make sense to send them as a texture array, in which case you'd use [`-[MTLRenderCommandEncoder setFragmentTextures:withRange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515878-setfragmenttextures?language=objc).